# Load Structs in C

Tags: c, struct

In my header file I have defined some structs:

```
typedef struct { double X; } feature_t;

typedef struct
{
 int n;
 feature_t *Features;
 float *Weights;
} signature_t;
```

In my main code I declare some new structs and try to load them:

```
feature_t  *f_x;
int i;

memset(f_x,0,sizeof(feature_t)*n_x);

for(i=0; i<n_x; i++){
    f_x[i] = 100.0;
    w_x[i] = (float)p_x[i];
}
```

When I go to compile this, I get the following error:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘feature_t {aka struct <anonymous>}’ from type ‘double’
```

Why does the compiler having trouble loading this double into this field? I declared it as a double.

thanks!

Comment: `f_x[i]` is not a `double`. It is a `feature_t`. Try: `f_x[i].X = 100.0;`

Comment: If that is your whole code, you're storing values in an uninitialized array of feature_t objects.

Comment: o ya I also memset the thing - I'll add that

Comment: @yoshi avoid `memset` for initializing structs, it is more appropriate to use the `= {}` syntax instead.

Comment: @Dai what's the latter syntax you mention?

Comment: @kaylum I set the field as you suggested. The compiler doesn't complain but I get a seg fault when I run the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

The first: make your `feature_t` instance an "automatic" variable on the stack - so no extra work needs to be done, but you can't use the object from the caller of the function that creates it:

```
void doSomething(size_t n) {

    struct feature_t f_x[n];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        f_x[i] = {};
        f_x[i].X = 100.0;
    }
}
```

(Note the above example uses a VLA, this is not permitted in C++, only C99)

Because `f_X` lives in the stack, the `= {}` initialization syntax means the raw object data in the stack is zeroed out.

(Note that you cannot use the `={}` syntax to initialize a VLA, each element must be initialized individually)

The second is to use the heap, but you must ensure you deallocate the memory eventually otherwise it will be a memory leak:

```
void doSomething(size_t n) {

    struct feature_t* f_x = calloc( n, sizeof(struct feature_t) );
    if( f_x == NULL ) exit( EXIT_FAILURE );

    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        f_x[i].X = 100.0;
    }

    free( f_x );
}
```

In this case, `f_x` is actually a pointer to the array of `feature_t` instances that lives on the heap, so its lifespan is potentially beyond the `doSomething` function scope - however I called `free` before the function returned.

I used `calloc` which allocates and zeroes-out memory before returning control to the caller, whereas `malloc` only allocates memory and exposes what memory contents were there previously, which is generally undesirable unless you absolutely need the performance gains by not explicitly zeroing memory.

Comment: In my case, I'd use the second (I think).  Both malloc and colloc are giving me seg faults. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @yoshi How are they giving you segfaults? Please post your entire program source (in your Question posting) as well as the debugger messages verbatim.

Comment: here's the [header](http://pastebin.com/AQcnkQ3x) and [main](http://pastebin.com/bnHpRGNV) and [dump](http://pastebin.com/PBSXvvPN). I'm trying to compile C in MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

There is a compile problem and a run-time problem that needs to be fixed once the compile problem is out of the way.

The compile problem is that you cannot cast a `float` to a `struct`, even when the `struct`'s only field is a `float`. You need to assign it like this:

```
f_x[i].X = ... // some float expression here
```

The run-time problem is that `feature_t  *f_x;` pointer cannot be used like an array until you assign it some memory. Recall that pointers are not arrays. You need to do something like this:

```
feature_t  *f_x = malloc(sizeof(*f_x)*n_x);
```

Comment: It may be more appropriate to use `calloc` instead of `malloc` because it will also zero-out the memory first.

Comment: @Dai This has to be OP's decision. If he is forcing initialization anyway, `malloc` wins; if he wants some default initialization, `calloc` wins. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: I edited this to use memset - will that work? also I'm now getting a seg fault

Comment: @yoshi `memset` stands for "memory set", it does not work unless there is some memory to be set. You need `malloc` or `calloc`; plain `memset` will segfault on uninitialized pointer dereference.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks for clarifying that. I'm still getting a seg fault though. I also tried just loading `f_x[0].X = 100.0`.